# xslt match multiple elements, but contains cdata

Tags: wordpress, xslt, cdata

I'm stuck trying to wrote an XSLT that will select items with an category of "Featured", because the data inside category is wrapped in a CDATA.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <body>
            <h2>Matched Items</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//item[category/.='Featured']"/>
          </body>
        </html>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="item">
        <div class="news-item" width="100%">
          <div class="news-item-description">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear" />
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a sample of my data.  This is from a wordpress blog, so I cannot change the output.

```
    <items>
      <item>
        <category>
          <![CDATA[ Category A ]]>
        </category>
        <category>
          <![CDATA[ Featured ]]>
        </category>
        <description>This item should be in the output HTML</description>
      </item>
      <item>
        <category>
          <![CDATA[ Uncategorized ]]>
        </category>
        <category>
          <![CDATA[ Some other category ]]>
        </category>
        <description>This item should NOT be in the output HTML</description>
      </item>
      <item>
        <category>
          <![CDATA[ Uncategorized ]]>
        </category>
        <category>
          <![CDATA[ Featured ]]>
        </category>
        <description>This item should be in the output HTML</description>
      </item>
    </items>
```

The output I want looks like this:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>Matched Items</h2>
    <div class="news-item" width="100%">
    <div class="news-item-description">This item should be in the output HTML</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="news-item" width="100%">
    <div class="news-item-description">This item should be in the output HTML</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This seems like it should be easy. The combination of multiple category elements plus the CDATA wrapper has me stuck.  Thanks

Comment: What output are you actually getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//item[category/.='Featured']` is not even syntactically valid XPath, I assume that is a typo.

In any case, this is not about CDATA. CDATA is meaningless, it does not exist. It only matters during *parsing* of a document. When you get to use XPath on the input it is already gone.

You need to trim whitespace before you make string comparisons. Try:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//item[category[normalize-space() = 'Featured']]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As Tomalak pointed out the XPath you have isn't valid, and probably caused issues even *running* the XSLT. Tomalaks is probably the answer you are looking for, but if you aren't sure if featured might be within, *but not the only text within*, the category you could also use the `contains()` XPath function, like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//item[category[contains(text(),'Featured')]]"/>
```

If you change the `apply-templates` line in your XSLT this should work as expected.

Comment: No, you are right and I just need to get coffee. It's 6:30 a.m. here and I should not be answering SO questions yet. Will delete my comment. (At least the bit about the partial matches is still true..)

Comment: @Tomalak Coffee away friend, although its good to know about that shortcut when making 2.0 XSLs though. Thanks :)

Comment: But to answer your question: No, it would not have worked in XSLT 2.0 either. Functions like `normalize-space()` do not accept sequences of more than one element, so it would have led to a run-time error. In XSLT 1.0 functions that expect a string silently convert the first node of a node-set argument to string, potentially leading to unexpected behavior going unnoticed. XSLT 2.0 forces you to be more explicit with function arguments.